# ExternalInterface escapes strings using JSON conventions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm getting hundreds of lines in my trace log per second!

WARNING: For content targeting Flash Player version 14 or higher, ExternalInterface escapes strings using JSON conventions. To maintain compatibility, content published to earlier Flash Player versions continues to use the legacy escaping behavior.

I already found a question on how to prevent this warning. However, I'm using SWC libraries for my SWF. So I don't have their source code. I need a way to suppress this warning. I don't mind turning all warnings/errors off for this SWF. Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: See https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html

Answer (score 1):

Try add `debug=false` to compiler options.